# Label Icon and logo in action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-launcher, android-actionbaractivity

I am working with action bar in my app. I wanted to show app icon launcher different and app logo different that i am able to do. Now my challenge is i am trying to put app label
that is also displaying  below my app icon but while my app is getting launch for few second its getting visible  and when activity get loaded its got vanished. I want to remove app label at the launching time too. My app has different condition to load the content.
I also tried to pass the blank string in

```
manifest <activity android:label="@string/app_name"/>
```

its making app name invisible and i am putting this inside the intent filter

```
e.g.
<intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" 
         android:label="@string/app_name_blank"/>
```

I have tried following options:

```
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);//Extra
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try using WindowActionBarOverlay condition in your action bar.Maybe that can solve your problem.
and for the other solution ,try in your XML manifest activity 
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar